# Mapping drive from Citrix and remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix, mapping

Is it possible from a PC using a Citrix ICA Client to connect to Citrix XenApp, then from the XenApp have a RDP remote desktop connection a Server, then map a disk on the Server, such that the mapped disk is available from the PC?

Comment: Citrix is a company. Which of their products are you referring to?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet XenApp... but thats a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: @Nate good guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you install Hamachi or something similar on both your local PC and then Server.  This will allow you to create a private VPN directly between these two computers.  You can then browse to the server over network neighborhood and mount your network share that way.  For a simple comparison of these products, see: http://cubicgarden.com/tag/hamachi/